# Im trying to make a if statement to change a variable.I

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a fantasy human world population but something is not working, I added a comment on what I've been trying to fix but it's not working.

```
import time
import random
Humans = 1
Most_Humans = 0
Seconds_Alive = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    Seconds_Alive += 0.1
    Humans += random.randint(0, 10)
    Humans -= random.randint(0, 10)
    if Humans == 0 or Humans < 0:
        print("Theres no sign of humans. They only lived for", Seconds_Alive, "seconds and the most humans were", Most_Humans)
        break
    print(Humans)
    if Most_Humans < Humans:
        Most_Humans == Humans #should have made Most_Humans to Humans aka. 6 to 8 but it still says 0
```

**Output:** Theres no sign of humans. They only lived for (seconds) seconds and the most humans were **0**

Answer (score 1):

You are using two equal signs, the comparison operator. Fixed code:

```py
import time
import random
Humans = 1
Most_Humans = 0
Seconds_Alive = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    Seconds_Alive += 0.1
    Humans += random.randint(0, 10)
    Humans -= random.randint(0, 10)
    if Humans == 0 or Humans < 0:
        print("Theres no sign of humans. They only lived for", Seconds_Alive, "seconds and the most humans were", Most_Humans)
        break
    print(Humans)
    if Most_Humans < Humans:
        Most_Humans = Humans # works!
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change `Most_Humans == Humans` to `Most_Humans = Humans`